# Android - Hosting Application on Google Play Store (Developed on PhoneGap)

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build

I have one Application which is supposed to behave differently on Tablet and Phone.

My Questions

1. Can I host the Application with Same package name.
2. If the answer is Yes, then what line of code I might be missing in my config.xml application is getting overwritten.

I am new in hosting Application need help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, it is not possible to upload same application name or Same Package name

Answer (score 0):

You must use a different package names for each app. Package name is the identifier and unique for each application. Your package name must be universally unique (nothing that anyone else will ever use), and can never be changed. If you look into any application url in Google Playstore you can figure out "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos"

After the base url it appended the id which is your application package name. One url can never show two different applications.

This blog has good explanation about package names: http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does it mean, one .apk file can have one package name.?

Comment: Yes, each apk file should have unique package name. So, if you have to upload two apk files, then both of them should have unique package name.

For example:
phone : "com.android.appname.phone"
tablet : "com.android.appname.tablet"

Answer (score 0):

@Ameya, what you are reading *maybe correct*, but **you do NOT have to do that**. I have one App in Google Play that runs on phones and tablets. You download the same APK for either. If you look at the listing in Google Play, you can see the similar display for the Apps. One screenshot is the the tablet, the other is the phone. Google will NOT let you list the App for both devices unless you provide a screenshot for both devices (phone & tablet). https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsdmasterindex.hackerDojocal&hl=en

If you goal is to have the same App functions with slightly different behaviour, that that is okay.